# How to find the variables selected by the tearing algorithm in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I'd like to find the set of variables selected by the tearing algorithm in Dymola. so that I could know which variables link different parts of the system together. But I am not sure how to show these variables in Dymola.  I checked the help document of Dymola but didn't find anything related to how to show these variables.
[image]

Comment: Here is the link from the screenshot as real text / clickable link https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.571.9335

Comment: Same paper and many more also available here: http://people.inf.ethz.ch/fcellier/Lect/MMPS/Refs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to see it in `dsmodel.mof`, which is created after setting `Advanced.OutputModelicaCode = true;` or activating it in the UI using "Simulation Setup -> Translation -> Generate listing of translated Modelica code in dsmodel.mof".

Dymola will generate the relevant code in the `// Torn part`. Searching for this in `dsmodel.mof` is a good option as the file can get pretty big.

The exact code will depend on the type of problem. Two examples:

(1) A rather simple electrical like this
[image: RLC-circuit with algebraic loop]
will be solved symbolically, with the resulting code:

```
...
// Linear system of equations
// Tag: simulation.linear[1]
  // Symbolic solution
    /*  Original equation
    resistor1.v = constantVoltage.V-resistor.v-capacitor.v;
    */
    resistor1.p.i :=  -(capacitor.v-constantVoltage.V+resistor.R_actual*
      inductor.i)/(resistor.R_actual+resistor1.R_actual);
  // Torn part
    resistor.p.i := inductor.i+resistor1.p.i;
    resistor.v := resistor.R_actual*resistor.p.i;
    resistor1.v := resistor1.R_actual*resistor1.p.i;
// End of linear system of equations
...
```

In this case the tearing variable is `resistor1.p.i`, with the equation to compute it stated directly there.

(2) Translating `Modelica.Thermal.FluidHeatFlow.Examples.TwoMass` will give you a non-nonlinear case, i.e. when an iteration is needed to solve the system of equations. You should find something like:

```
...
  // Start values for iteration variables of non-linear system of 1 equations: 
  //   pipe2.V_flow(start = 0)
algorithm // Torn part
  pipe2.flowPort_a.m_flow := pipe2.V_flow*pipe2.medium.rho;
  pipe1.flowPort_a.m_flow :=  -(pipe2.flowPort_a.m_flow+ambient1.flowPort.m_flow);
...
```

The tearing variable is `pipe2.V_flow` in this case, with the start value for the iteration.

Comment: When using commercial libraries in Dymola, I can't generate .mof files. Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

In Dymola 2021X, we could use `Equation Incidence Browser` to see which variables are used in the nonlinear equations, I guess these variables could be treated as tearing variables. And this works for commercial libraries, too. But it is a pity that Dymola 2021X doesn't allow showing details of nonlinear equations.
[image]